How to raise an error, when the IF statement is TRUE?
I want to use recursion from reverse. I am trying to add all the values in the recursion to a memo object.
I am using visual studio code.
I have an error in the line
if( key==n) return memo[n];
In the last iteration it raised undefined error.
But up to the last iteration the line is not giving any error. I am printing the key and n variable.
When I check inside the if clause there is a value in the key but there is no key variable.
inside if, the key does not exists.
Any idea?


const factorial = (x=0,n=0, memo={})=> {const key = x ;}
console.log(key);
console.log(n);
if (key==0 || key==1) {memo[key]=1;}
if(key!=0 && key!=1) {memo[key]=memo[key-1]*key;}
if( key==n) return memo[n];
factorial(x=key+1,n,memo)
};
console.log(factorial(x=0,n=3));



this states that problem is in the if clause
if(1==1 ) return memo[key];
this replacement again raised error
if(key==key) return memo[n];

the closed curly bracket at the end of first line is the issue

Just remove the end } bracket in the first line.


const factorial = (x=0,n=0, memo={})=> {
    const key = x ;
    console.log(key);
    console.log(n);
    if (key==0 || key==1) {
        memo[key]=1;
        
    }
    if(key!=0 && key!=1) {
        memo[key]=memo[key-1]*key;
        
    }
    if( key==n) return memo[n];
    factorial(x=key+1,n,memo)
    };
console.log(factorial(x=0,n=3));




The extra curly bracket at the end is the issue. Please check below corrected code.
const factorial = (x = 0, n = 0, memo = {}) => {
  const key = x;
  if (key == 0 || key == 1) {
    memo[key] = 1;
  }
  if (key != 0 && key != 1) {
    memo[key] = memo[key - 1] * key;
  }
  if (key == n) return memo[n];
  return factorial((x = key + 1), n, memo);
};
console.log(factorial((x = 0), (n = 5)));


Although its not the optimal code but can do the job.
Why not simply iterate and multiply.

Thank you very much. I am trying to speedup grid traveller question. First I added a line to the text book example.
I added const key2 = n+','+m;
Now I consider to go forward from beginning with the same logic in factorial.
const gridTraveller = (m,n, memo={})=>
{
console.dir(memo)
const key = m+','+n;
const key2 = n+','+m;
if (key in memo) return memo[key];
if (key2 in memo) return memo[key2];
if (m==1 && n==1) return 1;
if (m==0 || n==0) return 0;
memo[key]=gridTraveller(m-1,n,memo)+gridTraveller(m,n-1,memo);
return memo[key];
};
console.log(gridTraveller(3,3));

Please update the question instead of pasting code in comments
